# path.resolve("") returns root directory ("/") when packaged Electron App is run on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, path, electron

I created Electron application and packaged it with electron-packager.

Then, I ran packaged application on MacOS (XXX.app), and I found that path.resolve("") returns root directory "/".

When I ran this application on Windows/Linux, path.resolve() returns directory where application file is located. (for example: /home/nutti/XXX)

So, I didn't understand this behavior, and I want to know how to get application directory in MacOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`path.resolve()` takes an existing path as an argument, when nothing given, it will return the current working directory on Windows and Linux and the root on macOS (because both Windows and Linux pass Node relative paths, macOS doesn't).

You can use `process.cwd()` to get the working directory of your application, which will always work on any platform.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. ```process.cwd()``` get same result from executing from .app

Comment: @nutti That's strange. In my experience this should work. I've also tested it on various systems.